# Flutter: BuildLayouts for landscape and portrait mode

Tags: flutter, orientation, landscape

I am working on the first screen of a Flutter App and want to make him adaptable to screen size and orientation. As I only develop for mobile, the size is no big problem, but searching for good solutions for landscape mode, the only method I found is making a whole new layout for it.

Is this really the only solution, if you dont want your clients to have to scroll all the time or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MediaQuery` or `OrientationBuilder` and based on the output render `Widgets` on screen.

**OrientationBuilder:**

It's giving callback for the orientation of the device and based on that render widgets on the screen

```
new OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return new GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode, or 3 columns in
      // landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
);
```

**MediaQuery:**

This is statement based query used when orientation need on any click event or timer where based on that specific calls can be performed,

```
var isPortrait = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
```